# what does exc_breakpoint mean crashlytic?

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

why on iOS crashlythics very often does not display the cause of errors or crashes even the keys also often do not explain the cause of the error. is it normal to happen?

[this my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad5j6.png)

```
 @objc func getUserInventory(){
    DispatchQueue.global().async{
        self.giftController.getUserInventory(limit: "100", offset: "0") {[weak self] (success, gifts) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                if success {
                    guard let gifts = gifts else {return}
                    let addItem = Inventory(id: 0, name: "", description: "", imageSPath: "", imageMPath: "", imageLPath: "", value: 0, regDate: "", updDate: "", coinUserId: 0)
                    let filteredGifts = gifts.filter({$0.value != 0.0})
                    let sortedGifts = filteredGifts.sorted(by: {$0.id < $1.id})
                    self?.giftList = sortedGifts
                    self?.giftList.insert(addItem, at: 0)
                    if (self?.giftList.count)! < 9 {
                        self?.giftCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
                    }else{
                        self?.giftCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
                    }
                    self?.giftCollectionView.reloadData()
                }else{
                    let alert = AlertViewController.build(with: "Failed to get inventory")
                    self?.present(alert, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

crashes occur in line

```
if (self? .giftList.count)! <9 {
```

Comment: Use the TXT button and check the trace

Comment: What message did you expect?

Comment: I'm sorry for my question, I just read the EXC_BREAKPOINT documentation. I just dive into swift and get crashes like EXC_BREAKPOINT where there is no detailed explanation of the crash so it makes me confused @Larme

Comment: You have a file `CommentAndApprecitationViewController.swift`, and a method `getUserInventory` where call multiples closures, in one of them, it's crashing, why? I can't guess like that without the code.

Comment: `(self? .giftList.count)! <9` Why do you use the force unwrap: `!`, what does it mean to you? Once you know that, check if it should be possible or not (meaning if there is another mistake somewhere else causing the issue). If not, properly use if let, guard let, or ??.

Comment: right, but the question I mean is why sometimes ios / swift catches different errors in crashlythic? sometimes there is an error explanation like the following https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7gmc.png and sometimes it doesn't exist, like 'EXC_BREAKPOINT' Can you explain it as simply as possible? @Larme

Comment: Different crash errors, different messages error. That's all. Behind EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Etc, there can be various reasons. You don't develop with Xcode? You'll see this kind of message in Xcode, it's not related to Crashlytics, but rather "iOS".

Comment: yes you're right, thanks for explaining to me. really appreciate your opinion and answer @Larme